# Error in Running abaqus cae command from command line interface

Tags: python, python-2.7, abaqus

How do I know the working directory of python prompt so that I can run my scripts by keeping it in the folder? Is it the same as the Abaqus working directory?
If that's the case I am unable to run the file

```
abaqus cae noGUI=test.py
```

gives the following :

> abaqus cae noGUI=test.py
>
> Abaqus Error: The following file(s) could not be located: test.py

Although the file is present. Running the file from File->Run gives the correct output
**Edit**: I am using Abaqus 2016 version

Comment: test.py was a file which created a truss in abaqus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my error by going into the directory where test.py was present.
The abaqus working directory isn't related to this issue

Answer (score 0):

To access the version of python that is included with abaqus, you need to enter `abaqus python test.py`
where test.py is your script
hope this helps